# TableView is not reloading after data passing from object

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiactivityindicatorview

Iam working on Iphone app. I am using `NSObject` file for all `webservices` parsing `Asynchronously` and also used the protocol method to pass `webservice` result (typically `NSMutableArray`) to `ViewController`.

Then i displayed the result in `tableview`. But my problem is table is not reloading, because after calling protocol method, controller return to `NSObject` file and table is not reloading.

I also tried to take method `-(void)tableReload` to say the two statements

```
[tblview reloadData];
[spinner stopAnimating];
```

in protocol.

i am calling `tableReload` method after protocol first method called.

Here is the my code:

```
-(void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{

//My parsed data is stored in array
id<EventRepository>aReposit;

    aReposit=(id<EventRepository>)eventLVC;
    [aReposit successResponse:array];
    [aReposit tableReload];

}

-(NSString *)successResponse:(NSMutableArray *)sresponse

{

//This is my first delegate method in protocol
//storing sresponse array value into another array here and using this array in tableview methods

}

-(void)tableReload

{

    NSLog(@"This is TableReload Delegate Method in ListViewController");
    self.tblView.delegate=self;
    self.tblView.dataSource=self;
    [self.tblView reloadData];
    [self.spinner stopAnimating];

}
```

After calling above two methods control return to Object file and activity indicator is not stopping and table is not reloading.

Please can any body give ideas or suggestions to solve this problem.

Thanks

Comment: relaod TableView after your NSmutableArray addObject

Comment: Could it be that you forgot to link the outlets ? Check the controls for being `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

First -> is your tableReload method is getting called ?

If YES,

Regarding TableViewData - check the data which you are displaying it on table. Whether its content has been changed or not. Try using NSLog.

Regarding Spinner - Is your IBOutlet connections are properly connected.

If all is well than, Try calling tableReload on main thread.

Comment: HI my reloading problem is not solved, tableReload method is getting called, but table not reloading, i think control goes to object file after calling protocol delegate method. Plz tell me any ideas

Answer (score 0):

Stop the spinner at the delegate function.

```
 -(void)tableReload
    {
        [self.spinner startAnimating];
        self.tblView.delegate=self;
        self.tblView.dataSource=self;
        [self.tblView reloadData];
    }


 -(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        if([indexPath row] == ((NSIndexPath*)[[tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows] lastObject]).row){
            //table view loaded succesfully
            [self.spinner stopAnimating];
        }
    }
```